# No whitespaces between variables

Tags: powershell, space

Newbie to powershell I'm working on a TXT file to exchange data between two processes.
I'm using the following rows to extract data from an XML file to the TXT file

```
$xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.efile_reference | Out-File $Workpath\test1.txt -NoNewline
$xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.eclient_id | Out-File $Workpath\test1.txt -Append
```

Now my problem is that there is no blank space between the two variables as I need.

The result is

```
E:\EM\e_storage\exp6272001752216699873.jpg241505829
```

... but I need

```
E:\EM\e_storage\exp6272001752216699873.jpg 241505829
```

with a space between the two variable. No metter if I must add an echo line or something else...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you don't try to write a space you won't get one,  Something like `Add-Content -Path $Workpath\test1.txt -Value ' '` might work.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the string before outputting to the file, much easier that way:

```
@(
    $xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.efile_reference
    $xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.eclient_id
) -join ' ' | Out-File $Workpath\test1.txt -NoNewline
```

The above joins the values of `efile_reference` and `eclient_id` with a space using the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.2).

Other way to construct the string can be interpolating these values in a [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.4#double-quoted-strings) using the [`$( )` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--):

```
"$($xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.efile_reference) $($xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.eclient_id)" |
    Out-File $Workpath\test1.txt -NoNewline
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: it joins the two values in a single string separated by a single space, then pipes the result to be appended to the chosen file
You can have it on a single line, I split it for clarity.

```
$xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.efile_reference, 
$xmlElm.emXML.e_image_storage_entry.eclient_id  -join ' ' | 
    Out-File $Workpath\test1.txt -Append
```